# Specifying the location of WEB-INF for a legacy Tomcat application

Tags: jsp, tomcat, configuration

I am attempting to build a test setup for a legacy Apache/Tomcat application.  To be honest, I am not sure if it is an 'application.'  It is a collection of JSPs that happen to be in a certain directory.

The jsps are being displayed properly.  The problem is that the classes folder in the WEB-INF folder isn't being found - I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError exceptions.

To complicate things, there are *two* 'apps' and they share a WEB-INF:

```
4 drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root         4096 Dec  2 09:38 thing1
4 drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root         8192 Dec  2 09:38 thing2
4 drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root         4096 Dec  2 09:38 WEB-INF
```

So in this sanitized-for-your-sanity example, we see the two 'applications' and the shared WEB-INF folder.

One URL that works is *http://mysite/thing1/index.jsp*  When we try to log in from that page, however, we get the NoClassDef error.

Here's the relevant part of the server.xml file.  So the actual path of the index.jsp file mentioned previously is *tony/ROOT/thing1/index.jsp*

```
  <Host name="tony.com" appBase="tony/ROOT">
      <Alias>111.111.111.111</Alias>
      <Context path="" docBase="" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" />
  </Host>
```

My question is, how do I have to configure Tomcat so thing1 & 2 use WEB-INF for their lib and class folders?  These 'apps' aren't being deployed as war files...

(note - making a copy of the production box would be difficult - there's a lot of stuff running there.  I am attempting to pare it down to make a test environment for a few apps.)

Comment: You've actually a single application with two subfolders, not two applications. Which class is missing in the classpath according to the `NoClassDefFoundError`? Do you know that loose `.class` files should go in `/WEB-INF/classes` and that classes packaged in `.jar` files should go in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Yes.  The class files are in WEB-INF/classes, the jars in WEB-INF/lib.  The class in question is in a _subdirectory_ in classes, however, based on its package name.  It's there, Tomcat just can't see it.  Privileges are ok.

Comment: I moved the files from tomcat/tony/ROOT to tomcat/webapps as per @Bozho's comment below.  Now I get the following different error: _org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file.  Only a type can be imported. rpsi.rpsiMeWeb resolves to a package_  This is index.jsp.  It was compiling properly before I moved the code to _webapps_ so it's nothing but a config issue.

Comment: @BalusC I had no luck at all when WEB-INF was directly under webapps (and parallel to my thing1 and thing2 folders.) When I moved WEB-INF under webapps/thing1,  thing1 started behaving better.  Could the directories directly under webapps be _magical_ somehow and define applications?

Comment: This JSP compile error is under the covers caused by a `NoClassDefFoundError`. You should in fact put the webapp on `Tomcat/webapps/ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

A web application must have the following structure:

```
tomcat/webapps/appname
tomcat/webapps/appname/*.jsp
tomcat/webapps/appname/WEB-INF
tomcat/webapps/appname/WEB-INF/lib
tomcat/webapps/appname/WEB-INF/classes
```

So that way it should work, without any additional xml configurations

Comment: Indeed, that stuff is all there. Hmmm.

Comment: So the directory directly under the webapps directory is 'the application' then?  And as such defines the location for WEB-INF if we're making a typical installation?